# How to prove that a field has cylindrical symmetry

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry

In Physics there are many fields with cylindrical symmetry, that is, they depend solely on the distance $r$ between a point $P$ in space and an axis or line $a$.

I have these examples:
In module:
$$E=E(r)=\frac{2k_e\lambda}{r} \quad \text{(Electric field generated by a charged line.)}$$

$$B=B(r)=\frac{2k_mI}{r} \quad \text{(Magnetic field generated by a line of a current $I$.)}$$

I see that every formula have $r$ to the denominator.

> How could one prove that such fields, starting from their formula, have a cylindrical symmetry? And what is the best definition of cylindrical symmetry?

Comment: It is not clear what you are really looking for. One can obtain solutions that obey certain symmetries by imposing the necessary constraints on the equations of motion. Then they would have these symmetries *by construction*.

Comment: @flippiefanus Now is it clear?

Comment: Not sure. What you seem to be asking for is rather obvious. If you express the "formula" (which I assume is the expression of the field) in cylindrical coordinates and it does not depend on the angular coordinate then the field is cylindrically symmetric. If it does depend on the angular coordinate then it is not cylindrically symmetric. That's basically it (apart from some caveats)..

Answer (score 1):

Cylindrical symmetry means they only depend on the distance to the axis and not on the angular position nor the height ($z$). Hence, as long as $r$ is not the distance to a point, but rather to the axis, and the field depends exclusively on $r$, we can tell it is cylindrically symmetric.

Notice that an angular unit vector does depend on the angle, and hence a cylindrically symmetric field cannot point in an angular direction. It can point upwards/downwards and away/toward the axis, though.

Comment: I knew this fact.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer it in the context of a PDE. If you have a PDE,
$$Lu=f,$$
where $u$ is the solution and $f$ is the source.

To check if your problem has cylindrical symmetry, you check if $u(x)$ is a solution, then is $u(Qx)$ also a solution, for all roataions Q with the axis along $e_3$. This means that it is rotationally invariant. Now to check invariance under translations along $e_3$. Thus if $u(x)$ is a solution, then so should $u(x+ce_3)$ for all $c$. These two facts together imply cylindrical symmetry along $e_3$.

In general replace $ce_3$ and $Q$ with operators
$$Lu=f\implies Lu(Tx)=f(x)$$
then you have symmetry with operator $T$.